# GitHub For Windows Login to visualstudio.com

Tags: github-for-windows

I am using GitHub for Windows to mange a clone of 1 of my repositories on visualstudio.com (part of TFS hosting with GIT support). GitHub for Windows prompts me for login, but the OK button remains disabled even if I type in a username and password. Is there some sort of setting I need to change to allow logging in to my repo?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, this was not an issue with my GitHub credentials but with my credentials connecting to a clone of one of my tfs.visualstudio.com repositories. My username is my email address which contains a period and an @ which didn't play nicely with with the GitHub for Windows client. The fix was to enable alternate credentials in my tfs.visualstudio.com profile and to set a username without the invalid characters. Everything works fine using the alternate username to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution for me, hope this helps someone else.

You could add Alternate authentication credentials on account's Security page of your Visual Studio Online. Then Github app would ask you to provide this credentials.

Secutiry settings page link is on your profile menu. Here is the source link:
http://mohamedradwan.com/2015/10/11/sync-between-my-github-and-visual-studio-online/

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the last version and is working fine, I just login with my github account, do you have one right?, maybe you are getting confused with the colors of the interface they are all kind of grey.

Make sure your github account is correct, try downloading the last version http://windows.github.com/release-notes.html